# unable to scale yaxis in d3.js according to the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the below code, I am unable detect why my y-axis is shooting above my maximum value.

x.domain works fine in below code but y.domain does not. However, if I give static values that i have commented below, my line graphs works perfectly but I want to make it dynamic.

**My csv Data has 3 columns**

column names are **date**,**for** and **act**.

date is parsed into date format while for and act columns are numbers.

The Idea for graphing two columns is coming from [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-more-than-one-line-to-graph-in.html)

Currently my graph looks like this.
[image: line graph]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 70},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
          .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(13);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(7);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")    
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.for); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.act); });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("for.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.for = +d.for;
    d.act = +d.act;
  });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date;}));
    y.domain([5000, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.for, d.act); })]);
    /*y.domain([5000, 15000]);*/


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y",6);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("stroke" ,"red")
      .attr("d", line);

svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("stroke" ,"blue")
      .attr("d", line2);    
});


</script>
```

Comment: is 15000 the maximum you are expecting?

Comment: also try adding an additional line in function(d), like so: function(d) { console.log(Math.max(d.for, d.act)); so you know what your function is actually doing. check your console for the output.

Comment: no 15000 is just a random number, The values move along 10000-12000. Thanks for the console.log suggestion. Here is what i found the code is comparing column2 i to column3 i and then outputs the max and so it loops and gives me a total of all max.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the max of your two columns you could use:

```
d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max([d.for, d.act])
})
```